# SerenityJs with webdriverio support instead of Protractor

Tags: serenity-js

Is it possible to use Serenityjs as plugin for webdriverio or wd.js instead of protractor?

If yes - Can someone provide any example/sample code? 
If no  - Is there any plan to roll out this feature?

We already have test framework in webdriverio so dont want to convert whole project to serenityjs/protractor

Answer (score 1):

Serenity/JS doesn't support webdriverio or wd.js out of the box just yet, but you could use [@serenity-js/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@serenity-js/core) to integrate Serenity/JS with your webdriver flavour of choice.

The implementation would probably look similar to [serenity-protractor](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/tree/master/packages/serenity-js/src/serenity-protractor), so you'd need:

- an `Ability`, wrapping webdriverio/wd.js client; similar to [BrowseTheWeb](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/blob/e8155e0499c29570268a701af5849965251220d2/packages/serenity-js/src/serenity-protractor/screenplay/abilities/browse_the_web.ts) for Protractor
- some [Interactions](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/tree/e8155e0499c29570268a701af5849965251220d2/packages/serenity-js/src/serenity-protractor/screenplay/interactions), wrapping the method calls on your client of choice
- some [Questions](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/tree/e8155e0499c29570268a701af5849965251220d2/packages/serenity-js/src/serenity-protractor/screenplay/questions) to read the data from the page
- and your client-specific version of the [Target](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/blob/e8155e0499c29570268a701af5849965251220d2/packages/serenity-js/src/serenity-protractor/screenplay/ui/target.ts) class

[This thread](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/issues/6) should give you some more context.

Comment: I've been creating a setup for cypress today and followed the same approach as described here. It's not too challenging to do and works fine!

Comment: That's sounds cool, @Michael! Would be great if you could share your Cypress setup with the community if you can :-)

Comment: I am still in a very early fase but I was thinking about providing it to the serenity-js repo or as a package for Cypress. @Jan Molak

Comment: Awesome, feel free to reach out to me on Github or LinkedIn if you have questions